# When I use VS Code write Vue.js, the code color sometimes get chaos

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, format

as shown below:
[image]
I don't understand why, the syntax and format is correct, it's extremely confusing.

I review my code carefully but can't figure out

Answer (score 6):

this seems to be a bug with VS Code. This could be because VS Code is not updated, or an extension that is not supported anymore.

first, try `ctrl + shift + p` and running `>Developer: Reload Window` this should reload your current environment and the error should be fixed.

If that doesn't work, try a different extension. I currently use [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur), and [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

And don't forget to make sure your VS Code is up to date. go to the bottom left and click the settings cog, then `check for update` or `updates`.

Comment: Vetur is working great for me on Visual Studio for Mac. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is, "*Start from scratch, and record your steps.*"  I'm happy to share my notes on what is presently working: https://github.com/TheAutomaTom/VsCodeSettings-Vue3

My personal machine had been in that spot for some weeks, so I took a step back and dump out your cornucopia of extensions and their dependencies.

- Only run pertinent language services.  This is a tall order given how much a Vue + Typescript + Tailwind on Vite app covers.  I am suspicious of generalized HTML/CSS/JS packs though, because they may not be built to parse Vue SFCs. Every new release of a services intended for other frameworks, like Angular or React, are still possible culprits (and moving targets).
- I gave up getting Prettier and ESLint on stable ground.  For a non-workplace thing, I feel okay about that.  You may be having issues with a global package, if you've been experimenting.  I've tossed out a couple branches following different tutorials.  I intend to revisit this one since it has some example projects: [rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint](https://github.com/idahogurl/vs-code-prettier-eslint)
- I've noticed the Volar team seems to let [oddities squeak out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72523087/vue3-ts-all-global-compnents-throw-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any) a little more frequently than I remember in Vetur.... but we love them just the way they are.  Sometimes I downgrade just to check if I've gone crazy, yet.

Comment: Also... these freak'n extension bundles are madness.