# Vue3 + TS: All global compnents throw "JSX element type '___' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

Every globally registered component has a red typescript squiggle in markup!  The app still runs, like there are no errors!

- It happens on all components, custom made *AND* third party libs.
- It does ***NOT*** throw an error if I import them directly into the vue file.

Boring example of registering a component

```ts
//main.ts
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent.vue";
_app.component(MyComponent,  "my-component");
```

Boring usage

```html
//SomeView.vue
< script setup lang="ts>
import OtherComp from "./components"
</script>

<template>
  <div>

    <my-component> 
      <!-- Red Squiggles! -->
    </my-component> 

    <OtherComp> 
      <!-- no error on local import-->
    </OtherComp> 

  </div>
</template>
```

What the heck is going on?  Did I accidentally update typescript or Volar or a linter or something? It's a fake error, right?  Sure is ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error comes from Vue Language Features (Volar).

[issue page](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1405)

Rolling back the volar plug-in to version 0.36.1 can solve this problem.

Comment: As of 0.37.3 which is the current version in this moment, the error was fixed

Answer (score 1):

Just change the volar version **0.37.2 to 0.36.0** and everyting will be fine.

Note: I spent coulple of hours and didn't find the exact solution and then simply tried this; then everything worked fine.

This link helped to get some idea regarading this issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28631#issuecomment-472606019

Answer (score 0):

According to the [issue page](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1405), add this config to your tsconfig.json file:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "experimentalSuppressInvalidJsxElementTypeErrors": true
  }
}
```

update:
the volar have updated to version v0.37.3 to resolve this issue.so,just reinstall the volar.
that works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed on `0.37.3`, so you don't have to alter your config or anything -  https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1405#issuecomment-1149618450