# Strictly a linting error: "JSX element type 'X' does not have any construct or call signatures" in VueJS, when globally registering components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Everything is working properly. I am able to use the components and was even able to build the app without issues, but my text editor (VS Code) still throws a linting error. Registering my own components throws the same error. This particular project uses Electron, but I still have the same issue when attempting to create a project with the actual CLI. This is a fresh machine, and everything has been installed today if it matters.

Vue: v3.2.36
Vite: v2.9.9
Node: v18.3.0
NPM: v8.11.0

client.ts (my init file); changing the name to main.ts does not fix the issue.

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { Icon } from "@vicons/utils";
import {
    NButton,
    NCard,
    NTabs,
    NTabPane,
    NInput,
    NInputNumber,
    NSelect,
    NDataTable,
    NButtonGroup,
    NScrollbar,
    NModal,
} from "naive-ui";

const app = createApp(App);

app.component("Icon", Icon)
    .component("Button", NButton)
    .component("Card", NCard)
    .component("Tabs", NTabs)
    .component("TabPane", NTabPane)
    .component("Input", NInput)
    .component("InputNumber", NInputNumber)
    .component("Select", NSelect)
    .component("DataTable", NDataTable)
    .component("ButtonGroup", NButtonGroup)
    .component("Scrollbar", NScrollbar)
    .component("Modal", NModal)
    .mount("#app");
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
        "paths": {
            "@components": ["./components"],
            "@domain": ["./domain"],
            "@helpers": ["./helpers"],
            "@views": ["./views"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["./**/*.ts", "./**/*.d.ts", "./**/*.tsx", "./**/*.vue"]
}
```

Image of the linting error:
[image]

Not sure if this is relevant, but I've been getting this warning in my terminal as well:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Vue3 + TS: All global compnents throw "JSX element type '___' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72523087/vue3-ts-all-global-compnents-throw-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any)

Issue was with the newest version of the Volar extension. Changing the version back to 0.36.1 solved the issue for me.

Comment: The issue was fixed in the latest Volar release 0.37.3.