# JSX element type 'RouterLink' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, vuejs3, vue-tsc

I've found a lot of issues regarding this across the internet and stack overflow, however, the problem always seems to be with React? like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call), however, I am using Vue and the error happens to Vue's own components which are part of a freshly installed project I made to test out types and in general type hinting

**Error:**

```
src/App.vue:3:6 - error TS2604: JSX element type 'RouterLink' does not have any construct or call signatures.

3     <router-link to="/sales-running">Sales Running</router-link>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vue-sales-running",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "watch": "build --watch",
    "strict": "vue-tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.37.1",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "watch": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  }
}
```

**App.vue** (The place it complains)

```
<template>
  <nav class="flex m-auto justify-center">
    <router-link to="/sales-running">Sales Running</router-link>
  </nav>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind variants;

#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav {
  padding: 30px;

  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

I've made a custom `strict` script/command which executes the `vue-tsc --noEmit` command, this command does what I expect and now stops my script compiling if it does not match the types expected.

However I now have another problem, is that I get errors from Vue's own prebuild components which are used for navigation?

Comment: Got the same issue with FontAwesome Icons in Vue. It worked two days ago, but today I get "JSX element type 'FontAwesomeIcon' does not have any construct or call signatures."

Answer (score 1):

As Jacob answers in [this](https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/226#issuecomment-1148428282) Github issue, we need to import our components to get us the right types and resolve our errors, do also note that he wrote at the end:

***Do note that this is not a permanent fix, just a workaround.***

So basically we need to import our components:

For the App.vue file we now have to import the components in the bottom:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView, RouterLink } from "vue-router";
{
  RouterView;
  RouterLink;
}
</script>
```

So I guess for now this is what has to be done when using the composition API with typescript and the `vue-tsc` package

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in a newly scaffolded project via `create-vue`. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: Btw, the `{ RouterView; RouterLink; }` block is unnecessary and has no effect. `import`-ing a component in `<script setup>` is how to perform local component registration there.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72526508/strictly-a-linting-error-jsx-element-type-x-does-not-have-any-construct-or-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72523087/vue3-ts-all-global-compnents-throw-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any) sounds like a similar problem.

Apparently the Vue Language Features (Volar) extension is the issue, downgrade to 0.36.0

Comment: Volar is unlikely the cause since the `vue-tsc` command is run independently on the command line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).